# jQuery When changing an IMG SRC knowing when the image is done loading

Tags: jquery, css

I have a list of thumbnails. When a user clicks on a thumbnail I'm going to show the full-size image... Question is I want to show a spinner until the image is fully downloaded. is there a way in jQuery to know when an image is fully loaded and ready to be rendered in the browser?

Also is there a way to get the image dimensions before the image is fully downloaded?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

When the thumbnail is clicked show the spinner. Then add a function to the [load event](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) of the image that hides the spinner.

You can use a serverside language to get the size of an image. PHP has [getimagesize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php)

Answer (score 3):

Paul Irish wrote a nice little plugin that should solve your problems. It accepts a callback function that is fired when a given image is finished loading. Unfortunately because jQuery's native .load() method doesn't work with cached images this is needed.

https://gist.github.com/268257

```
// $('img.photo',this).imagesLoaded(myFunction)
// execute a callback when all images have loaded.
// needed because .load() doesn't work on cached images

// mit license. paul irish. 2010.
// webkit fix from Oren Solomianik. thx!

// callback function is passed the last image to load
//   as an argument, and the collection as `this`


$.fn.imagesLoaded = function(callback){
  var elems = this.filter('img'),
      len   = elems.length;

  elems.bind('load',function(){
      if (--len <= 0){ callback.call(elems,this); }
  }).each(function(){
     // cached images don't fire load sometimes, so we reset src.
     if (this.complete || this.complete === undefined){
        var src = this.src;
        // webkit hack from http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-dev/browse_thread/thread/eee6ab7b2da50e1f
        // data uri bypasses webkit log warning (thx doug jones)
        this.src = "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///ywAAAAAAQABAAACAUwAOw==";
        this.src = src;
     }  
  }); 

  return this;
};
```

Comment: Thanks but this is a block of code. Know of any pages that tell you how to use it or a tutorial? demo? example?

Comment: Here you go https://gist.github.com/663023 #image is the image id and #loader would be the id of the loader image.

Comment: I don't get it. Where is the IMG src? How does this get called? My flow is, user clicks a thumb, I use the thumb to get the fullsize image URL, then I want to load it, while loading show a spinner, after the image is done loading, remove the spinner and show the image?

Comment: It seems like you'd much prefer a jQuery plugin that handles the whole process as opposed to what has been provided here. I would suggest http://fancybox.net/

Answer (score 0):

Check out a working example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/treeface/u4rs5/2/

Basically, you can create a `new Image()` var in Javascript and attach a callback function to the load event such that it sets the display image to the same src when it's ready to go.

**Edit**: This works in every browser I've tried, including Opera, Safari, Chrome, Firefox, IE6/7/8/9.

Comment: k thought it worked but it doesn't It doesn't call the loading if the image is already loaded which means the loading div doesn't go away... Also, what does this do? (var loaderImg = new Image(),
    src = "http://imgur.com/XW6BQ.jpg";) I need to be able to get the SRC of the HREF of the clicked AHREF with the jQuery Bind Function, this gets real messy. Ideas?

Comment: @AnApprentice You could just put a conditional check in there to see if the image's src attribute is equal to the href you want to load. If it is, just skip the loading process, or fake a reload. To load the selected href value, just use the `this` selector to find the clicked element's href attribute and set it equal to `src`. All of this can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/treeface/u4rs5/4/